# Unable to install ODBC Driver (DLL) on windows without MSI

Tags: windows, installation, odbc, driver

We have implemented an ODBC Driver for some data source, and tested it on Linux with UnixODBC Driver Manager.  This driver is supposed to work on Linux as well as Windows. So, we want to deploy and use this driver on windows too. We built this driver code on Windows, created a 64bit driver DLL using Visual Studio 2010 premimum edition.

Now, we want to install this Driver on Windows, register it with microsfot Driver Manager and then test it using some application. We do not have MSI/setup installer for this driver. So we want to install this driver (Dll) manually on Windows.

We tried using "regsvr32" tool on Windows with following command: "regsvr32 ", and getting following error: 
"The module  was loaded, but the entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found"

We seached on net and it seems this command looks for some entrypoint function which is not there in our DLL. Is it required for DLL to have this function?

After doing some investigation on web, and found some methods like InstallDriver, ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver needs to be implemented as a part of Driver. We do not have these methods implemented in our Driver, would this be a problem? Are these methods needed in ODBC Driver code to install a driver dll?  This code also has one method named "DLLMain". Is this requierd in typical ODBC Driver implementaiton on windows?

Is there any other way to install our ODBC Driver (DLL) on Windows? 
Please suggest if you have similar experiences, or we are missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need "regsvr32" to register a COM/ActiveX .dll.

Not all .dll's are COM/ActiveX - it sounds like yours isn't.

Not all programs need .msi - perhaps a simple filecopy is sufficient.

SUGGESTION:

If you copied this .dll from somebody else ... then read their installation instructions!

Comment: Thanks. The DLL is not copied from anywhere, we generated by compiling our code (which runs on Linux) in visual studio.

Comment: You copied the source code for the .dll, correct?  Where exactly did you get it from?  And did it have a "README", or other installation/usage notes?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and had to implement all the methods that were needed. As far as I know DllMain is not necessary. But I never worked with odbc dll drivers.